# AVAsset tracks is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

Essentially I am looking to concatenate `AVAsset` files. I've got a rough idea of what to do but I'm struggling with loading the audio files.

I can play the files with an `AVAudioPlayer`, I can see them in the directory via my terminal, but when I attempt to load them with `AVAssetURL` it always returns an empty array for tracks.

The URL I am using:

```
NSURL *firstAudioFileLocation = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", workingDirectory , @"/temp.pcm"]];
```

Which results in:

```
file:///Users/evolve/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8BF465E8-321C-47E6-BF2E-049C5E900F3C/data/Containers/Data/Application/4A2D29B2-E5B4-4D07-AE6B-1DD15F5E59A3/Documents/temp.pcm
```

The asset being loaded:

```
AVAsset *test = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:firstAudioFileLocation options:nil];
```

However when calling this:

```
NSLog(@" total tracks %@", test.tracks);
```

My output is always `total tracks ()`.

My subsequent calls to add them to my `AVMutableCompositionTrack` end up crashing the app as the `AVAsset` seems to not have loaded correctly.

I have played with other variations for loading the asset including:

```
NSURL *alternativeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"temp" withExtension:@"pcm"];
```

As well as trying to load AVAsset with the options from the documentation:

```
NSDictionary *assetOptions = @{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: @YES};
```

How do I load the tracks from a **local resource**, recently created by the `AVAudioRecorder`?

**EDIT**

I had a poke around and found I can record and load a .CAF file extension.

Seems .PCM is unsupported for AVAsset, this page also was of great help. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avfiletype

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An AVAsset load is not instantaneous. You need to wait for the data to be available. Example:

```
AVAsset *test = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:firstAudioFileLocation options:nil];
[test loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"playable",@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{

    // Now tracks is available
    NSLog(@" total tracks %@", test.tracks);
}];
```

A more detailed example can be found [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronouskeyvalueloading/1387321-loadvaluesasynchronouslyforkeys).

Comment: This has helped massively, and but it still returns an empty array. After looking into it using AVKeyValueStatus it seems Linear PCM is unsupported for AVAsset? Am I misunderstanding and is there a list of supported types for composition?

Comment: Your .pcm file is raw? That's not a supported format (oddly enough), if you put a wav header on it, it will work.

Comment: Pay attention that this procedure working well for .mp4 videos but NOT for HLS(.m3u8) videos.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409687/cant-able-to-get-video-tracks-from-avurlasset-for-hls-videos-m3u8-format-for