# Can't able to get Video Tracks from AVURLAsset for HLS videos(.m3u8 format) for AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, m3u8, avkit

I am developing a custom video player to stream HLS videos from server. I can successfully play HLS videos using AVPlayerItem and AVPlayer.

After that I want to add subtitle track and audio tracks for my video player. So I used AVMutableComposition to do so. So now the issue is when I am creating AVURLAsset for HLS Videos, I can't able to get video tracks from AVURLAsset. It is giving me always 0 tracks. I tried "loadValuesAsynchronously" of AVURLAsset and I tried adding KVO for "tracks" of AVPlayerItem. But None of these producing me any positive result.

I am using the following code.

```
  func playVideo() {
    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL!)
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    // Video
    let videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    do {
        let tracks = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)
        guard let track = tracks.first else {
            print("Can't get first video track")
            return
        }
        try videoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: track, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    guard let subtitlesUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "en", withExtension: "vtt") else {
        print("Can't load en.vtt from bundle")
        return
    }
    //Subtitles
    let subtitleAsset = AVURLAsset(url: subtitlesUrl)
    let subtitleTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .text, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    do {
        let subTracks = subtitleAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.text)
        guard let subTrack = subTracks.first else {
            print("Can't get first subtitles track")
            return
        }
        try subtitleTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: subTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    // Prepare item and play it
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: composition)
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init()
    self.playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.playerLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
    self.playerLayer.player = player
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)
    self.player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
    self.player.play()
}
```

This procedure working well for .mp4 videos but not for HLS Videos(.m3u8). Anyone have some working solution for this?

or

How can we get tracks from HLS videos using AVURLAsset? If this is not possible then How can achieve similar result ?

Please let me know you feedback.

Many more thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For HLS video `tracks(withMediaType: .video)` will return an empty array.

Use this instead: `player.currentItem.presentationSize.width` and `player.currentItem.presentationSize.height`.

Pls let me know if it works.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the exact same problem as you. But I got around a similar problem (querying for HDR) by instead of querying the tracks on the AVURLAsset, I queried the tracks on the AVPlayerItem.

Set up an observer on the item status:

```
player?.observe(\AVPlayer.currentItem?.status,
                                         options: [.new, .initial], changeHandler: { [weak self] player, _ in
                                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                self?.observedItemStatus(from: player)
                                            }
                                         })
```

Then query the AVMediaType of your choice (in your case text).

```
func observedItemStatus(from avPlayer: AVPlayer) {

    guard let currentItem = avPlayer.currentItem else { return }

    // ideally execute code based on currentItem.status...for the brevity of this example I won't.

    let hasLegibleMedia = currentItem.tracks.first(where: {
        $0.assetTrack?.mediaType == AVMediaType.text
    })?.assetTrack.hasMediaCharacteristic(.legible)
}
```

Alternatively if you need more than just a Bool, you could do a loop to access the assetTrack you really want.